# Exclude data points from a Render plot with reactive variables

Tags: r, shiny

Currently i am exploring the possibilities to build `Shinny` Dashboards. I would like to create a dashboard where users can exclude data from a plot. The data is obtained by an excel sheet that which is selected by the user.

```
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput('datafile', 'Choose xlsx file',
                  accept = c(".xlsx")),

        uiOutput("x"),
        uiOutput("y"),

      ),
      mainPanel(plotOutput("plot",click = "plot1_click",
                           brush = brushOpts(
                             id = "plot1_brush"
                           )),
                uiOutput("Exclude"),
                uiOutput("Reset")

    )
  )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    Data <- reactive({
      infile <- input$datafile
      if (is.null(infile)) {
        return(data.frame())
      }
      read.xlsx(infile$datapath) %>%
        select_if(colSums(!is.na(.)) > 0) 
    })

    output$x <- renderUI({
      if (ncol(Data() > 0)) {
        selectInput("x", "x-axis", names(Data()), selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE)


      }
    })

    output$y <- renderUI({
      if (ncol(Data() > 0)) {
        selectInput("y", "y-axis", paste0(names(Data())), selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE)


      }
    })

    vals <- reactiveValues(
      if (ncol(Data() > 0)) {
        keeprows = rep(TRUE, nrow(Data()))
      }
    )

    observeEvent(input$plot1_click, {
      if (ncol(Data() > 0)) {

        res <- nearPoints(Data(), input$plot1_click, allRows = TRUE)

        vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
      }
    })
    observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle, {
      if (ncol(Data() > 0)) {

        res <- brushedPoints(Data(), input$plot1_brush, allRows = TRUE)

        vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
      }
    })
    observeEvent(input$exclude_reset, {
      if (ncol(Data() > 0)) {
        vals$keeprows <- rep(TRUE, nrow(Data()))
      }
    })


    observe({
      if (ncol(Data() > 0)) {
        data    <- Data()[ vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]

        output$plot = renderPlot({
          ggplot() + geom_point(data=data, aes_string(x=input$x, y=sym(input$y),color = NULL))


        })
      }
    })

  }


  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I do get the following error : `Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.`. 
I expect that it has something to do with the fact that I use `reactiveValues`, but I do not know how to solve it.

Could somebody help me?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions to try:

- In your `ui` you probably want `actionButton` for your `exclude_toggle` and `exclude_reset`
- Create your `reactiveValues` separately and default to NULL for `keeprows`
- After you read in your data file, set your `keeprows` to TRUE
- Don't put your `output` inside of an `observe`. Instead, you can just reference `Data()` so it will change when new data is loaded
- I removed `sym` from your plot as you were using `aes_string`, and wasn't sure if you had something else intended

I tried to keep most of the rest the same, let me know if this works for you.

```
library(shiny)
library(openxlsx)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('datafile', 'Choose xlsx file',
                accept = c(".xlsx")),
      uiOutput("x"),
      uiOutput("y"),
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot",click = "plot1_click",
                         brush = brushOpts(
                           id = "plot1_brush"
                         )),
              actionButton("exclude_toggle", "Exclude"),
              actionButton("exclude_reset", "Reset")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  vals <- reactiveValues(keeprows = NULL)

  Data <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      return(data.frame())
    }

    mydata <- read.xlsx(infile$datapath) %>%
      select_if(colSums(!is.na(.)) > 0) 

    if (ncol(mydata) > 0) {
      vals$keeprows = rep(T, nrow(mydata))
    }

    return(mydata)
  })

  output$x <- renderUI({
    if (ncol(Data() > 0)) {
      selectInput("x", "x-axis", names(Data()), selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE)
    }
  })

  output$y <- renderUI({
    if (ncol(Data() > 0)) {
      selectInput("y", "y-axis", paste0(names(Data())), selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE)
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$plot1_click, {
    if (ncol(Data() > 0)) {
      res <- nearPoints(Data(), input$plot1_click, allRows = TRUE)
      vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle, {
    if (ncol(Data() > 0)) {
      res <- brushedPoints(Data(), input$plot1_brush, allRows = TRUE)
      vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$exclude_reset, {
    if (ncol(Data() > 0)) {
      vals$keeprows <- rep(TRUE, nrow(Data()))
    }
  })

  output$plot = renderPlot({
    req(input$x, input$y)
    mydata <- Data()[vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]
    ggplot() + 
      geom_point(data=mydata, aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y, color = NULL))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very nice solution. I really appreciate your help. To comment on the question why I did use the `sym` for the plot, this was basically a quick and dirty solution for the fact that the column names of the excel files that users will select often contain spaces. This is not recognized by `ggplot` . By using `sym` I created a workaround, but it is not a very elegant solution. If you have any ideas how to do this better, I would be happy to hear. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I think I understand. But when you read in an Excel file with read.xlsx, aren't the spaces already getting converted in the column names to periods?